# How to figure out where new NaNs are coming from - R

Tags: r, datetime, timer, nan

```
Total_Time <- function(TT_column){
z <- dmy_hms(TT_column)
hr <- hour(z)
min <- minute(z)
sec <- second(z)
x <- hr*60 + min + sec/60 # No need to extract days as the maximum value is 13 hours
x
}

df$TT.Col_1 <- Total_Time(df$T.Col_1)
sum(is.na(df)) # 0
df$TT.Col_2 <- Total_Time(df$T.Col_2)
sum(is.na(df)) # 0
df$TT.Col_3 <- Total_Time(df$T.Col_3)
sum(is.na(df)) # 0
df$TT.Col_4 <- Total_Time(df$T.Col_4)
sum(is.na(df)) # 0
df$TT.Col_5 <- Total_Time(df$T.Col_5)
sum(is.na(df)) # 5
df$TT.Col_6 <- Total_Time(df$T.Col_6)
sum(is.na(df)) # 7
```

I'm trying to figure out where come from those NaN values with `tryCatch()` but I can't figure out a way to use `tryCatch()` with those specific columns (`TT.Col_5` and `TT.Col_6`).

Some context: `T.Col_X` are character times values (`dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`) which are converted to minutes as they start in `30/12/1899 00:00:00` as 0 hours, 0 minutes, and 0 seconds passed. `Total_Time` is the function that convert those values and it restores them in `TT.Col_X`

Comment: Please provide some data with your question. for example the output of dput(head(df)). To help you identify the problem it's necessary to know more about the data you are working with. The output of summary(df) would also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I found it applying the transformation without the function in the code lines where the NaN comes from, for example:

Instead of:

```
df$TT.Col_5 <- Total_Time(df$T.Col_5)
```

I did:

```
z <- dmy_hms(df$T.Col_5) # Here was the problem
hr <- hour(z)
min <- minute(z)
sec <- second(z)
df$TT.Col_5 <- hr*60 + min + sec/60
```

And what was the problem? I found 5 empty non-NaN values. The same for `df$Col_6`, but 7 non-NaN values instead.